# AWS Load Balancer and IIS Virtual Directory

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, virtual-directory

I am migrating a project to the cloud with the aim to load-balance the website.

It is currently .NET Core app hosted on IIS, but there is a Virtual Application attached to this site in IIS (for a very old MVC3 application):

> **www.mysite.com** hits the .NET Core app

But

> **www.mysite.com/blog** hits the completely separate MVC app.

I want to dockerise my application and run it behind Elastic Beanstalk, or even just some EC2 instances behind a load balancer, but how can I take care of the "blog" app in this scenario? It 100% doesn't need to be load balanced and I don't want to make it part of the deployment strategy, since it is a simple CMS and the code hasn't been re-deployed for years!

EDIT: I'm thinking the Load Balancer provided by AWS must be the thing I am looking for, since it will be linked to the DNS entry and as it is effectively a reverse proxy, I should be looking to see if I can configure the Load Balancer to add a rule to reverse proxy the request into one of my EC2 boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I take care of the "blog" app in this scenario?

You can use [Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html). You can have different listeners handling different URLs (e.g. one listener handles www.mysite.com and another one handles /blog).
You can add more sophisticated rules for /blog to forward its handling to different target groups.
Target groups can contain ECS, EC2 and whatever you need.